# What is the life of an infinite loop send to background?

Tags: bash

When will an infinite loop end?

E.g. if I run

```
while :; do sleep 1; date +%s; done &
```

when will this end — on closing the terminal or on shutdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you provide `&` at the end, it goes into the background. Whether it is killed or not depends on how you close the terminal.

If you close the terminal application itself (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, press the x in the window decoration, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for `gnome-terminal`), it kills the background process.

But if you close the terminal using `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it continues to run, even if you log out (unless it is a GUI application). It will end when you shut down.

(I do not know why there is a difference between the two. I suspect that when you close the application, the operating system closes it and its children.)

The following is different:

```
nohup while :; do sleep 1; date +%s; done &
```

The `nohup` command detaches it from the terminal. However you close the terminal, the command will continue to run until you shut down (logging out is not sufficient) or kill the command manually.

When you use `nohup`, the output goes to `~/nohup.out` unless you manually redirect the output.

P.S. The command will not work with `nohup` as given, because `nohup` does not take a compound command. But you could script it and run the script with `nohup`.

P.P.S. It is easier to see what is going on by running a GUI. Instead of the `while`… command, I run this:

```
gcalctool &
```

Much quicker and easier to see what is happening, as the calculator disappears when it is killed; and you can kill it easily (just close the calculator).

Comment: @choroba says 'If you supply & a the end, closing the terminal will not close the process' i'm confused.

Comment: I have tested my answer. I run the loop without `nohup`, close the terminal, but the process is still there.

Comment: See also http://seejeffrun.blogspot.cz/2008/05/bash-nohups-background-jobs.html

Comment: totti - You can test it yourself. @choroba - that article is out of date. I wonder if you are using a different version of Ubuntu? It very definitely goes away when I close my terminal! I am using 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: @PaddyLandau: See a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eM-uzU9Bc0c). I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: @choroba - Fascinating! With some experimentation, I have noticed that it makes a difference whether you close using `exit` (or `Ctrl`+`D`) or closing the running terminal application.  

When I close the running terminal (press the x in the window decoration), it kills the process. But if I close using your method (`exit` or `Ctrl`+`D`), it continues to run! So, we have a complex answer, and I shall modify my answer to reflect this.  

Thank you for your continued efforts.  

I would _love_ to know why there is a difference!

Comment: @choroba - I have edited the answer.

Comment: @PaddyLandau: I think I get it now: Bash does not send the `nohup` signal to its background children upon normal exit. But, if you close the terminal window, the shell running in it recieves a nohup signal, and it correctly propagates it to the children. I verified it with `strace`.

Comment: @choroba, that is interesting indeed. Thank you for following that up.

Answer (score 2):

If you supply `&` a the end, closing the terminal will not close the process. It can still be killed by a TERM or KILL signal, though. On shutdown, TERM and KILL are sent to all the processes.

Comment: Is `while` is a process ? How can i know the pid to kill (`ps aux` ?)

Comment: @totti: After starting the background process, bash will tell you on stderr, or you can use the special variable `$!`.